# Why did the title "Rav" appear after Hillel and Shammai?

Tags: tannaim, beis-shammai, hillel

IIRC, the word Rav appears in the Tanakh as an adjective ("עצום ורב" or "רב לכם בני לוי". Probably in Jonah 1:6 "רב החובל" it is a name?).

Earlier leaders (Moses, Yehoshua, judges, prophets) and earlier Rabbis (Zugot) weren't called "Rav". All of sudden "Rabbis" appeared in different forms: Rabban, Rabbi, Rav, Rebbi, etc.

Why after Hillel and Shammai, did the tradition break, and the title "Rav" appear?

Answer (score 1):

In Lecheker Shemot Vekinuyim Batalmud, on names and nicknames in the Talmud, Rav Reuven Margolies write (2:13):

[image]

That is, before the "Rabbanim Gedolim" had a political power, but no more after Hillel and Shammaï, so they added a title to emphasize that.

Comment: Can you please take a better picture, I can't read after "במידה...". And how "תואר רבנות" is connected to their political activities?

Comment: I don't have the sefer, I screenshoted from here : https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22322&st=&pgnum=11 
I think they added a title that is clearly Torah-y (Rabban) to show that they have no more political power

Comment: Can you transcript it to your best? I also do not see a special explanation of the need to add a title as the generations degenerated.

Comment: שמותיהם בלבד, ללא כל תיאור נוסף, כמו הנשיאים הקודמים, שהיו להם גם כוח פוליטי. וכותרתו של הרב התווספה מאוחר יותר, כשכוחם פחת והם היו רק מורי תורה (ראו את ספרי יסוד המשנה בעמוד 12), מלבד רבנו הקדוש שכונה "הנשיא" מכיוון שהיה גם הנציג הפוליטי של העם.

It's not a real transcription (I wroted in frensh then translated), but it's how I undertood.

Maybe the title added was vis a vis of goyim, to "explain" them that they was not political and should not be worried of a revolt (didn't work well with Rabbi Akiva thru)

Answer (score -2):

You are correct that the sage Hillel had no title. The term “rabbi” was first used by Rabban Yohanan ben Zakkai when he inaugurated the idea of rabbis, hakham, “knowledgeable ones." In Israel the rabbis were called rabee while the ones in Babylon were referred to as rav.

Comment: Rabee? Not Ribbi?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, Rebbe.

Comment: “Why... did the tradition break?”

Comment: Sorry, again, the question asks why this was instituted, not when or by whom.

Comment: @AlBerko It was instituted because when the temple was destroyed in 70 CE the temple no longer existed and Jews had to preserve Judaism some other way, w/out the temple.

Comment: I don't see any logic here, because the temple was destroyed they started to call each other Rabbi?

Comment: @AlBerko Yes. The priest no longer existed since the temple was destroyed. People started to refer to private teachers called "rabbis" rather than the temple-oriented Judaism.

Comment: And how did they address Hillel? Hi, Hillel? Hillel said? I don't see any necessity to add the title after the destruction

Comment: @AlBerko Hilel most likely didn't hold any titles. They probably called him Hillel.